# Разработка на Битрикс24

Tags: windows, веб-программирование, 1с, битрикс24, it-бизнес

1. Встречал вакансию - Разработчик Битрикс24. В чем заключается разработка на битрикс24 (ведь как сказано на [Битрикс24](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%8124) Битрикс24 — российский сервис для управления бизнесом, грубо говоря эта программа рассматривалась мною как пользовательская офисная программа как Word)?
2. Подскажите пожалуйста бесплатную литературу по битрикс24.

Comment: Предположу, что хотябы для начала нужно знать `Написана на: php, mysql, javascript, html, css`.. + от себя.. разработчик битрикс далеко не придел мечтаний, ищите дальше

Answer (score 1):

Битрикс 24 - можно рассматривать как фреймворк, на котором написана бизнес логика приложения заказчика;

Разработка на битриксе сводится к изменению/добавлению кода на php (по правилам фреймворка); Порог вхождения на мой взляд - низкий; По крайней мере любую задачу можно попытаться реализовать своими силами имея минимальные представления о php и о  битриксе; Сам на битриксе не работал, но посмотрел курс 25 уроков на ютубе. Найти который элементарно. Отмечу что курс смотрел давно, вполне возможно что сейчас битрикс уже другой. Впечатления - простые вещи делаются достаточно легко и удобно.